# Draw multiple instance of same image on surfaceview's onDraw efficiently

Tags: android, surfaceview

I'm trying to make a game that has many instances of the same image in different locations. I was hoping to declare the image once, and then use that bitmap in the onDraw(). However, when I use any sort of variable that's been declared in the class, I get an error because it's note keeping it's values.
I just moved over to using surfaceview, so maybe I'm missing something with that. I'm currently just trying to draw one image, but the idea's the same and will be used once I get to the multiple instances.
What I have right now:

```
class GameView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback
{
    private GameThread _thread;
    // vars for display, scale, etc
    private int displayWidth;
    private int displayHeight;
    private double scale;
    private Bitmap groundPic;

    public GameView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // set the surface holder for callback
        getHolder().addCallback(this);
        _thread = new GameThread(getHolder(), this);
                displayWidth = getWidth();
        displayHeight = getHeight();
        scale = displayWidth / 512.0;   // ground image is 512;
    }
@Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {

        groundPic = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ground);
        groundPic = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(groundPic, displayWidth, 50, true);
        canvas.drawColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.background_colour));
        // draw ground                  
        canvas.drawBitmap(groundPic,0, getHeight() - 50, null);
    }
```

This causes a force close because displayWidth is 0. Am I wrong in setting the values in the constructor? I tried making an init() that I called from my activity after I created the view and before I setContentView(). 
I know it works if I put all of the settings inside onDraw(), but I felt like it was really inefficient. 
What I was hoping to do (but caused errors) was to have the init() and inside of that, set the groundPic which would be a class variable, and then my onDraw would be small and fast since it wouldn't keep making this same bitmap object over every cycle. I'm going to be drawing 30 missiles around the ground too, so it would be a huge waste to make 30 of the same bitmap every cycle when I could just make it once, and then drawing it with the specific locations 30 times. 
If anyone can help point me in the right direction to get this working properly, it woudl be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This causes a force close because displayWidth is 0. Am I wrong in
>   setting the values in the constructor?

Yes, since normal behaviour dictates that the `SurfaceView` will not have been laid out yet when it's constructed. In stead, you should use the [`SurfaceHolder.Callback`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceHolder.Callback.html) to discover any changes relevant to the `SurfaceView` its size and format. Your code snippet suggests you probably already have the relevant methods present:

```
class GameView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback
```

Since you're implementing the `Callback`, you should have the `surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height)` method somewhere. You can use the passed in `width` and `height` parameters to calculate the scale and appropriately scale down the `Bitmap`. Similarly you could do the loading of the image in `surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder)`.

For more pointers on using `SurfaceView` and threaded drawing, you may want to take a look at Google's [Lunar Lander sample project](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/LunarLander/index.html), especially the [`LunarView`](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/LunarLander/src/com/example/android/lunarlander/LunarView.html) class.

Comment: That's great thank you! I decided to try out Handlers and Runnables and that's working alright so far, but on the next game I'll definitely try out the SurfaceView (using relative layout to set all positions was more work than necessary). 
Great pointers, I really appreciate it.